# How do I set my event listener to capture an event through the shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, shadow-dom, custom-element, custom-events

I have a custom element which has a number of other custom elements in its shadow DOM. I want those child elements to react to an event the parent dispatches, so I set the composed flag to true, like

```
const matchingEvent = new CustomEvent('match', {
      composed: true
    })
this.dispatchEvent(matchingEvent)
```

and in the child element I set capture to true, like

```
this.addEventListener('match', this.#onMatching, {
      capture: true
    })
```

The event isn't captured, though. Is composed the wrong flag for capturing events from outside the shadow DOM, or is there another problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble UP the DOM.

So the child needs to listen at an element **above** where it was dispatched.

And you probably want `bubbles:true` also for that CustomEvent

Comment: Yes, but the capturing phase goes down the DOM, right? I guess I could add an event listener on the parent, but that would make a new dependency, which I'd rather not have.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, I can say, but it creates a circular dependency.